# sql select string coming before space dash space

Tags: error-handling

select string coming before space dash space

say table 1

id | name
 1 | Poo - SR
 2 | S-h-r - SR
 3 | SDR - mj
 4 | srk - kl

i want it like

id | name
 1 | Poo 
 2 | S-h-r
 3 | SDR
 4 | srk

Answer (score 0):

use REPLACE function in SQL?
example :SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghicde','cde','xxx');

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select left(@column, charindex(' - ',@column) - 1 )+' '+right(right(@column, charindex(' - ',@column) + 1),charindex(' ',right(@column, charindex(' - ',@column) + 0))+1)
```

Replace `@column` with your table column name